# How to pass custom variable in cart?

Tags: php, product, cart, opencart2.x

I am using `Opencart 2.0.1.1`. There is hidden text field on product page that I want to post on cart page. I am following [this tutorial](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=48664) but getting `Undefined index` issue.

```
<input type="hidden" name="design" value="12">
```

I have done the following coding so for:

In catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

```
$option['design']=$this->request->post['design'];
$this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'],$quantity,$option);
```

Then in `$data['products'][] = array(` added `'design'   => $product['design'],`

Then in system/library/cart.php

In `$this->data[$key] = array(` added `'design'        => $options['design'],`

Then in cart.tpl in view\theme\template-name\template\checkout\cart.tpl

```
echo $product['design'];
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Comment: I think, You need to specify with your code in your question for better question. What have you tried?

Comment: @HarnishDesign edited the question now.

Comment: can we see the actual code, tpl file / generated html would help to establish if the page & form is rendering correctly.

Comment: Man, do not edit it... If that is the cause of the problem, let us identify and point it to you

Comment: @CarlosCarucce Thanks for pointing but that was only writing issue. In actual code it is `design`

Comment: In the tutorial says that `add` just support 3 parameters `($product_id, $quantity, $option)`, and points that all the extra data should be passed through the `$option` variable...in your code you have 6 parameters!!

Comment: @Hackerman `$option` is not passing anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a null or invalid index your variable isn't being passed, I would make sure your input is inside the form being submitted and make sure you have it spelled right just in case. Also use php

print _r($_POST);

To verify if its posting the data. If you see it listed then double check your class method.

You would need to provide us with more content so that we could troubleshoot the issue more accurately.

Comment: Value is coming in `$_POST`